# How to execute a function which gets sleep and start after every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a text file which i am reading using a function.As per my requirement i have to use Threads to read this text file.I have instantiated a  thread which is executing the text file reading function.But i need to sleep the thread after every 5 seconds and re executes it after 2 seconds.

Here is my code.

```
Thread th = new Thread(readfromtexfiletoRichTextBox);
       th.Start();
```

readfromtexfiletoRichTextBox is the function to execute.

Please help me

Comment: why would you want your thread to sleep at all? its bad practice and wastes resources. what exactly are you trying to do within your app?

Comment: Explain `.But i need to sleep the thread after every 5 seconds and re executes it after 2 seconds`

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - because it's in the spec?   There is very little wrong with sleep if used for the purpose for which it was designed, and not for lame polling.

Comment: because its in the spec does not make it the right choice or approach. actually, there is ALOT wrong with thread sleeping...and was not designed for this purpose either. there are far more efficient ways of doing this.... without thread.sleep :). you will face ALOT of problems, will shoot yourself in the foot and the like. there is a reason why there are a lot of "outcrys" in the community for people using thread.sleep - there is a reason not to and I just said them. The rest...up to you :)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I know there are a lot of outcries, seemingly from developers who have either never actually delivered anything, or are totally clueless and just follow ridiculous thread-FUD.  There is nothing intrinsically wrong with Sleep() calls, there are not a LOT of problems.  Alternatives using threadpool timers etc. actually cause more overhead and often require redesigning code as state-machines instead of inline code.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with you there @MartinJames :)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - looks like we may have to agree to disagree.  I've used Sleep() calls for waits/delays, (those waits requested by specs, not for nasty polling loops etc), for 30 years plus.  No problems found yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep(5000) will sleep (and make the thread wait) 5 seconds

If you need to stop the thread after 5 seconds even after it hasn't processed the text file, and then re-execute it 2 seconds later, I'd suggest a "host" thread that ticks every 2 seconds, which will fire the thead that reads the file and after an iteration of 5 seconds, terminates it regardless.